# Golang API response 400

Tags: go

I can't see were is my error every time i try to run it i get nothing when i print some of the key variables i got this :

**print longURL**

> http://www.example.com

**print &output**

> &{400 Bad Request 400 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN]
>   X-Xss-Protection:[1; mode=block] Server:[GSE]
>   Alternate-Protocol:[443:quic] Content-Type:[application/json;
>   charset=UTF-8] Date:[Thu, 12 Jun 2014 02:10:33 GMT] Expires:[Thu, 12
>   Jun 2014 02:10:33 GMT] Cache-Control:[private, max-age=0]
>   X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff]] 0xc2100fe940 -1 [chunked] false
>   map[] 0xc2100581a0}

```
// c0de urlShort


package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type apiResponse struct {
    Id, Kind, LongURL string
}

func main() {

    longURL := os.Args[len(os.Args)-1]

    body := bytes.NewBufferString(fmt.Sprintf(
        `{"longURL":"%s"}`,
        longURL))

    request, err := http.NewRequest(
        "POST",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url",
        body)

    request.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    client := http.Client{}

    response, err := client.Do(request)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    outputAsBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    response.Body.Close()

    var output apiResponse
    err = json.Unmarshal(outputAsBytes, &output)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s", output.Id)

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of normal response, you are getting this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "resource.longUrl"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required"
 }
}
```

It says that you are missing required parameter: longUrl. Notice that it's long **Url** not long **URL**

This code works for me:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type apiResponse struct {
    Id, Kind, LongURL string
}

func main() {

    longURL := os.Args[len(os.Args)-1]

    body := bytes.NewReader([]byte(fmt.Sprintf(
        `{"longUrl":"%s"}`,
        longURL)))


    request, err := http.NewRequest(
        "POST",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url",
        body)

    request.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    client := http.Client{}

    response, err := client.Do(request)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    outputAsBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    response.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println(string(outputAsBytes))

    var output apiResponse
    err = json.Unmarshal(outputAsBytes, &output)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s", output)

}
```

Comment: Yup that worked @Kluyg i had named the longUrl ... wrong(LongURL)